# C# WPF Window: Top and Left coordinates not being updated on window maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a main WPF window. (henceforth, parent window). In this parent window I have a button. When button is clicked I open a custom messagebox window (henceforth, child window) in a position within parent window. When opening child window I pass as an argument the parent window, and another argument to indicate the child window where I want to locate it. Then within child window, according these parameters passed as arguments, I do some calculations based on the Top and Left coordinates of the parent Window.

I have seen that when parent window is maximized, then its Top and Left coordinates are not being updated, they are the same, I mean they keep unchanged keeping last values before parent window is maximized. Why?

As a result of this, when doing some calculations using Parent.Top and Parent.Left from child window, it is making my logic failing.

How can I obtain correct Parent.Top, Parent.Left and others like Parent.Height and Parent.Width from child window logic?

I use Visual Studio 2008 and NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: This is documented behavior: "When the Window is maximized or minimized, this value represents the top edge of the *restore point* for the Window.".  The restore point is where the window will resize back to when the user clicks the Restore button.  Several prior questions about this, find them by googling "wpf top property of maximized window".

Comment: @HansPassant thanks one more time. Brief and clear explanation. When window maximized, Top and Left are 0. Width and Height can be obtained using System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth and System.Windows.SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight